# Is margin interest applied to intraday trades?

Tags: stock-markets, margin

I'm trying to understand how the margin interest charge is calculated when you borrow money from a broker like Fidelity to buy stocks for  intraday trades.

If the rate is 8% then is the daily charge should be 8% / 365 or 0.0219% of how much you borrowed?  Or if you buy and then sell the stock on the same day  then the   broker does not charge you any interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you buy  the underlying on margin and you hold the position overnight then you owe the broker margin interest. This amount would be the borrow rate times the amount borrowed times the number of days held, divided by 365. There is no margin charge for day trades.